# What does it exactly mean by a 1 tier service?

Tags: web-services, service-layer

I would like to know what are the prime differences between 1 tier, 2 tier and 3 tier business services. What do they really mean when they say we have a 1 tier business service with some SLA(I know that it is their service time). I searched over internet but I couldn't find precise answers. Let's say we have a metadata repository which is exposed using restful web services or some other means, what feature makes it a tier one service?